# How to implement: UIViewContentMode ... Repeat?

Tags: ios, uikit, core-animation, quartz-graphics

UIViewContentMode covers a couple of positions you frequently need (Center, ScaleToFill, ScaleToFit), and a load that I suspect most people rarely use (TopRight, anyone?)

But it appears to be missing an obvious one: "Repeat".

Is there a way to efficiently repeat a UIView's contents? i.e. a tiled view, that as you resize it just uncovers / covers more of the tiled content?

(obviously, I am *not talking about UIImageViews* - UIImage/UIColor have a method for dealing with bitmap data, but that's a different problem. I'm talking about UIView, which means "drawRect"...)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my basic implementation, by hand. This is probably horribly low performance (presumably: it forces the view to redraw, instead of caching the output?)

TilingView.h

```
@interface TilingView : UIView

@property( nonatomic, retain ) UIView* templateView;

@end
```

TilingView.m

```
@implementation TilingView

@synthesize templateView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    int cols = 1 + self.bounds.size.width / self.templateView.bounds.size.width;
    int rows = 1 + self.bounds.size.height / self.templateView.bounds.size.height;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    for( int k=0; k<rows; k++ )
        for( int i=0; i<cols; i++ )
        {
            CGContextSaveGState(context);

            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, i * self.templateView.bounds.size.width, k * self.templateView.bounds.size.height);

            [self.templateView drawRect:rect];

            CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        }
}

@end
```